# capture pid process via R when using system()

Tags: r, pid

in windows, would like to capture java pid using R system() like the following:

`system("java -jar .\app.jar john_doe 1600_50_555", wait = FALSE)`

have tried:

`grep("^java.exe",readLines(textConnection(system('tasklist',intern=TRUE))),value=TRUE)`

would like to capture that pid without using grep() or additional filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ps` package for that.

```r
library(ps)
library(dplyr)

system("java -jar .\app.jar john_doe 1600_50_555", wait = FALSE)

pid <- ps() %>% 
  filter(name == "java.exe") %>% 
  pull(pid)
```